# Use Roles.GetUsersInRole for more then one role

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, simplemembership

Am using MVC4 SimpleMemebership in my application ..Am retrieving a list of all user in certain role using this :

```
     public ActionResult Index()
    {

        var s = Roles.GetUsersInRole("Admin");
        var m = Roles.GetUsersInRole("Member");

        return View(s);
```

you can see am passing the s list so am Only getting the user who have " Admin"Role. I want to have list of all user in (Admine and Memeber) in my list how to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to combine both results, first. Of course one user can be in multiple rules so you might get duplicate results which you have to eliminate then. You can do this using Linq:

```
return View(s.Union(m).Distinct());
```

Comment: Yes that what I need ....it work :)And if user have memember and Admin is Not duplicate too.

Answer (score 2):

There is no method for that. Maybe you could do intersection with Linq:

```
var s = Roles.GetUsersInRole("Admin").Intersect(Roles.GetUsersInRole("Member");
```

Comment: Careful, that is for getting all users in Admin AND Member roles, not users in only one of those roles. To get users in any of those roles you have to use Union instead of Intersect.

Comment: Oky I see :). I just try it , it helpful too :) .thanks